# How to animate :before selector with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animation, transition, pseudo-element

I have some element with :before pseudo selector define. I need to add some transition, animation for it but in CSS it's not possible. So i think that i can do this with jQuery but something is nor working right. Can you help me? This is my code:

```
var pilot = $('#remote_control'),
    pilot_shadow = $('#remote_control:before');
pilot.on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        pilot_shadow.animate({
            opacity: 0
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: There isn't a `:before` selector in jQuery. What is the element you'd trying to get?

Comment: You cannot use css pseudo classes as jQuery selectors.

Comment: is there any possible to do this in other way

Comment: Yes, but we need to see your HTML to know where to find whatever element it is you're trying to get at

Comment: maybe prev? http://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it's simple div with `:befor` pseudeo selector

Comment: i hope the first line has some syntax error. that line should end with a semicolon not by a comma

Comment: **`:before`** is a css selector **`.before`** is of jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/pseudo/jquery.pseudo.js

When you do this, it will work:

```
pilot_shadow = $('#remote_control:before');
```