# Toggle Class toggling, but not animating

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

This is directed towards a psuedo element `:after` :

```
 &:after {
    content:" ";
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:358px;
    left:263px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#f8f8f8 transparent;
    border-width: 0 23px 23px 23px;    
 }
 &.moved:after {
  left: 656px;
 }
```

And then what I do is .toggleClass to make it move :

```
$('#big-icon-nav').toggleClass( 'moved', 1000 )
```

And it moves, but it does not animate. Is this even possible? Why is it not?

Comment: can you show us a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: you are animating anything here. Ok looks like you are using kind of external CSS lib

Comment: I'm animating the `left` attribute. Ah, the CSS lib is Sass, the `&` just means it has the same common parent. in this case its `&` means `#big-icon-nav`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know jQuery can't really handle `:after` and `:before` pseudo-elements.
Do you really have to use an after element or would it be possible to do the same with a "normal" html tag?

If not you may want to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14399766/1903366)

Comment: Ah wow how did I miss that. Great point "There isn't a :before selector in jQuery." Thanks