# jquery animate won't trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a image move up at the moment you scrolled 100 or more pixels. When I turn on the alert the alert does trigger, but the animation doesn't. I can't seem to figure out where it goes wrong tho.

Could it be cause I try to change a ::before class?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 100 ) {
   //alert('scrolled');
            $('.flipje_pas::before').animate({top: -300}, 1000);
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Not sure why you are using the ::before   on top of the class. Usually, ::before is added after the page has processed. does it work if you remove that?

Comment: It does work without the :before but then it takes the whole row. The image is set on the :before class, so that's why I need the :before class.

Comment: Ah, I see. I found this, it may point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14399766/4515720